Error al tratar de enviar correo desde Wampserver
Me aparece el siguiente error al tratar de enviar un correo desde php con Wampserver:
Warning: mail(): Failed to connect to mailserver at "smtp.gmail.com" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set()
Ya instalé sendmail en la carpeta raíz de Wampserver y lo configure para usar gmail pero me sigue apareciendo el error.
Mi código es el siguiente:
<?php
$para = 'o...@gmail.com';
$asunto = 'Asunto del correo';
$mensaje = 'Este es el cuerpo del correo.';
$cabeceras = 'From: o...@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
         'Reply-To: o...@gmail.com' . "\r\n" .
         'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

if(mail($para, $asunto, $mensaje, $cabeceras)) {
   echo 'Correo enviado correctamente';
} else {
   echo 'Error en el envío del correo';
}
?>


Usa PHPMailer. Es mejor...

No se puede enviar correos con ninguna instrucción o aplicación de correo usando un smtp de gmail a secas; esto es por restricciones de Google. Hay artículos en internet que explican cómo crear una instancia en Google, y luego configurar PHPMailer. Busca artículos lo más reciente posible.
